# What are the best practices to upload bulk data in oracle table from C# using transaction and error handling?

Tags: c#, oracle, upload, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have requirement where i need to Import bulk data from a spreadsheet where one column is for Action Add/Update or Delete.
I need to upload this spreadsheet using web api and read data from excel file and according to action specified in the spreadsheet i need to insert/update or delete based on matching unique combination for the row. Also i need to return validation error messages stating the reason why data is not inserted for particular row or success message.
I tried with OracleBulkCopy but it doesn't return error messages for each row.

Answer (score 0):

OracleBulkCopy cannot perform `Update` and `Delete`.

If you want to create your own solution, I suggest you looking for ArrayBinding. You will be able to perform fast `Insert`, `Update`, and `Delete` operation with it.

There is no solution that allows you to know row by row the error message. The error message normally applies to the whole batch.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](https://bulk-operations.net/)

This project is not free, but if you want a built-in solution to perform all operations, this one could work for you.

```
// Easy to use
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
bulk.BulkUpdate(dt);
bulk.BulkDelete(dt);
bulk.BulkMerge(dt);
```